# Filling in the blank lines in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a script, there can only be two lines in this script! My problem concerns INFO skates, sometimes one of the rows is empty, can it be done so that if it is empty then it is filled with the data that is in the second line ??

```html
select           o.VALUE_NUMBER as transaction_value_number
                , i.VALUE_STRING as reader_value_string,
                , o.id
                , v.VALUE_STRING ||' '||c.VALUE_STRING ||' '|| x.VALUE_STRING AS  INFO
          from IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION o
              join IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  i 
                  on  o.parent = i.parent
            left  join IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  v
                   on  i.parent = v.parent
                   and  v.KEY = 'truck1'
           left  join IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  x
                   on  i.parent = x.parent
                   and  x.KEY = 'item_name'
           left  join IOT_STREAM_ANALYTICS_LOG_REPRESENTATION  c
                   on  x.parent = c.parent
                   and  c.KEY = 'truck2'
         where  i.key = 'reader' 
                    and i.VALUE_STRING = 'adc0156c-212d-11ea-80cb-e03f49835a25'
         and  o.key = 'transaction' 
         and o.value_number <> 0
          and v.VALUE_STRING ||' '||c.VALUE_STRING ||' '|| x.VALUE_STRING is not null
         GROUP BY o.id,o.VALUE_NUMBER , i.VALUE_STRING,v.VALUE_STRING ||' '||c.VALUE_STRING ||' '|| x.VALUE_STRING
```

Here is my answer
[image]

I want it to be like this:[image]

Comment: `v.VALUE_STRING ||' '||c.VALUE_STRING ||' '|| x.VALUE_STRING` is **NEVER** going to be null as, even if the `VALUE_STRING`s are all null you still have `' '||' '`.

Comment: Please help us to help you and [edit] your question with a [MRE] including a DDL statement for a (minimal) example your table (including constraints/relationships) and DML statements for sample data. Its much harder for us to help if we have to reverse engineer your structure/data from a query and output. And please do not post images of text; take the time to copy/paste and neatly format it as a table.

Comment: @MT0 I did as you advised and created demo data for the test https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a4acd3c2d1e512f9c7f92e85f9c924c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `analytical function` on top of your query as follows:

```
SELECT
    TRANSACTION_VALUE_NUMBER,
    READER_VALUE_STRING,
    ID,
       CASE
    WHEN TRIM(INFO) IS NULL THEN MAX(TRIM(INFO)) OVER(
        PARTITION BY TRANSACTION_VALUE_NUMBER
    ) 
   ELSE INFO
  END AS INFO
FROM (<YOUR_QUERY> );
```

This query is made considering that there are only two rows for single `TRANSACTION_VALUE_NUMBER` as mentioned by you in the question.

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks)))), but when I submit my request instead of "(<YOUR_QUERY>)", I have an error!

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7cf7f8f0910e9b4a86448bebbeca0839

Comment: `v.VALUE_STRING ||' '||c.VALUE_STRING ||' '|| x.VALUE_STRING` (aliased to `INFO`) is **NEVER** going to be null as, even if the `VALUE_STRING`s are all null you still have `' '||' '` and then the where filter (which will never be applied) will also prevent it from being null.

Comment: @MT0 I did as you advised and created demo data for the test! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a4acd3c2d1e512f9c7f92e85f9c924c

Comment: You can use TRIM. I have updated the answer to include the missing ELSE and END

Comment: @Tejash ? Thanks, this is what I wanted, but you can ask for one more, I want to integrate this code into another for further extension with other tables, but I get the error (but when I unplug the Where does grouping work) here is an example query. My goal is no line duplication !! And for that, I use grouping, but it doesn't want to do something! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5e4ea0c2d199420ba4e61dc78dc74f6

Comment: @Tejash I just want the examples that I threw out to the rest of the line not duplicated, I can not achieve it.Thank you for your help)I understand that the request is probably not complicated, but due to lack of experience I can not solve the problem with the takes!

Comment: Move the `trim` into your subquery, like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5b1d15202b04460063b88fa46662991

Comment: @kfinity Thank you, for the data is great, but when I was testing with all the data, there was a strange situation, with almost the same data, the result is still duplicated, I can not understand what, the data is almost identical, here is an example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a8c14ebe41707050d296e7fdef25431c

Comment: You joined your source table again, so of course your duplicate rows came back - you need to group by again. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b942c742af802df7af16555cdae6f8f

Comment: @kfinity  Me already
embarrassing to ask, but when I tested the query, there was one interesting feature, in the INFO box, there could be two different information (example in the appendix), and I want the information to be only and what is the maximum in number of characters (for example if there will be 95888137 MY_IDENT and MY_IDENT) I want to sign up for 95888137 MY_IDENT  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6edb8b040779522cca52802748bc3918